# No web processes running on Heroku with Sprint Boot

Tags: java, heroku

I have problem with doployment to heroku, I used Heroku CLI, but I can´t get even get it started as Dyno. I always get this error message:

[image]

I´m using Spring Boot 2.4.0.
With theese dependencies:

- spring-boot-starter-actuator
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-starter-web-services
- spring-boot-devtools
- h2 for db
- lombok
- spring-boot-starter-test
- springfox-swagger2
- springfox-swagger-ui
- spring-boot-starter-validation
- junit
- webapp-runner

I also have setted up Procfile with following:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/springBootExrcise-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I have tried using the Heroku webapp-runner plugin, still nothing.
When I run the app locally, everything works. Could someone shed some light ? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Have you tried scaling up your web processes, e.g. by doing [`heroku ps:scale web=1`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-ps-scale)?